# I want a unique result for my query.It should return only one result

Tags: oracle, union

Ok let me try to give a breif and as simple as possible explanation for my issue.

I have two queries .

Query 1:-

```
select columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD...
from tablex,tabley ....
where (set of conditions)
GROUP BY .... (all non aggregate function columns)
ORDER BY ... (two columns lets say columnB and columnC)
```

Please note here that columnA is actually an aggregate function .

Query 2:-

```
select '',columnB,columnC,columnD...
from tablex,tabley ....
where (set of conditions)
GROUP BY .... (all non aggregate function columns)
ORDER BY ... (two columns lets say columnB and columnC)
```

Pleae note that columnA is deliberately kept blank.The columns B,C,D are the same as query 1 as  well as the group by and order by clauses.
The where conditions in query 2 will have all the conditions related to the aggregation of column A omitted so this query WILL ALWAYS RETURN a result with column 'A' has blank for the same values of B,C,D.

I have done a union of the two queries as follows :-

```
QUERY2
UNION
QUERY1
GROUP BY...
ORDER BY...
```

Now here are some of the expected results:-

1. If any of  the where conditions in query 1 fail(this will happen if it
   finds that one of the tables in the where conditions doesn't have
   data for a given UNIQUE ID)then query 1 does not return any result
   in which case the results of query 2 are returned. This is perfectly
   fine.

   2. The where conditions in query 1 are all satisfied and we have one row returned. In this case query 2 will also return one row , therby resulting in the entire output having 2 rows ,one with a NON-NULL VALUE OF A followed by B,C,D and another row with a NULL VALUE of A followed by the same B,C,D values.Basically a duplicate row with only value of 'A' being different.

Scenario 2 is where I have a problem. I want a result where it only returns ONE ROW in scenario 2, i.e it should return the row with a NON-NULL value of A and discard the second row.

Is there any way I can have this done ?

I am using a Oracle12c database .

Comment: Is it necessarily true that column A will always be NOT NULL in the first query? (That is, NULL in column A can ONLY come from the second query?) Also: can you have the same value in columns B, C, D but different (non-NULL) values in A, in the first query? If so, how should these be handled? Otherwise the fact that the current output comes from a UNION of two queries is irrelevant; you have a set of rows, and for every combination of (B, C, D) you only want the rows with non-NULL A, **unless** the ONLY row with that combination (B, C, D) has NULL in column A.

Comment: Also - and very important - WHAT IS YOUR DATABASE, and its version? You have both the MySQL and the Oracle tags, that's no help.

Comment: oracle <> MySql

Comment: @mathguy many thanks for your feedback. To start off my database is oracle 12c.
Adding to this it doesn't really matter if column A is always NOT NULL in the first query because the when the where conditions in the first query will fail the query 1 to return a blank value, in which case I want to use the result of query 2 which is why i deliberately kept column a in query 2 blank.

Comment: @mathguy B,C,D are indeed unqiue and will always have the same value in both the queries. I want all rows with non-null values of 'A' UNLESS like you mentioned the only row with the same combination of B,C,D has NULL in column A

Comment: Littlefoot posted an answer already. It may not match your request exactly, but it's the approach you need... wrap everything in an outer query, group by B, C, D and select max(A) as A, B, C, D. Only order the result of the outer query (not the individual queries that participate in UNION).

Comment: @mathguy I have edited my question in hopes that it makes more sense... Please advise if the same solution can still be applied?

Comment: Yes - Littlefoot's solution is correct (even if the input data is not an exact reflection of your q1 and q2 output). You need something like this: assuming q1 and q2 are given (but without ORDER BY in them), `SELECT max(a) as a, b, c, d FROM (select <rest of q1 here...> union all select <rest of q2 here>) GROUP BY b, c, d ORDER BY b, c;` Note - UNION ALL will do the same job as UNION in this problem, and much faster.

Comment: The reason this is correct is how MAX works. If there are any non-NULL values, MAX returns the highest (in whatever sense) non-NULL value. But if all the values are NULL, then MAX will return NULL.

Comment: Another very silly question, does MAX return a value only if it has numbers in it? What I mean to say is what if my NON NULL Column A value has a combination of numbers and some characters... i am basically using -'rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement () ' ')).extract('//text()') ' '' to aggregate .Will max still work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this be OK? `q1` and `q2` represent your current queries.

```
SQL> with
  2    q1 as (select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c from dual union
  3           select 10, 20, 30 from dual
  4          ),
  5    q2 as (select null a, 2 b, 3 c from dual union
  6           select 10, 20, 30 from dual
  7          ),
  8    inter as (select a, b, c from q1
  9              union
 10              select a, b, c from q2
 11             )
 12  select max(a) a, b, c
 13  from inter
 14  group by b, c
 15  order by 1, 2, 3;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
        10         20         30

SQL>
```

Comment: I asked the OP a related question - whether it is possible to get TWO rows with the same B, C, D and different, non-NULL A's in the first query. If that is the case, he probably wants to keep both rows (rather than just the one with max(A), or min(A), or whatever).

Comment: @Barmar - CTE also works in old (and all newer) versions of Oracle. The OP better tell us what they are really using.

Comment: @mathguy, that's how I understood the question. You may be right, I don't know ... more than often, *answerers* have to be *mindreaders* as well. Sometimes we succeed, sometimes not. We'll see what the OP says.

Comment: Yes - and if in fact (B, C, D) is unique in the output of the first query, then your solution is the simplest answer.

Comment: Your CTE q2 is not a good reflection of the OP's intermediate result: in his case, column A is always NULL in q2. Rather, what you need to show is a row in q2 (where A is NULL as always) with values (B, C) that don't exist in q1.

Comment: That's not what I read, @mathguy. He said (for q2): "The columns B,C,D are the same as query 1" - I'd say that those values exist in both queries ... I did try to do what you suggested and used `null a, 200 b, 300 c` for q2, and my attempt returned exactly that as a result. What else would it return, if there's nothing to match in q1? Oh well ... getting late over here, I'm going to bed.

Comment: That is exactly what the OP said. Look at the SELECT for q2, it has hard-coded empty string for column A. What you just tried is correct - it is exactly what the OP said he needs to handle.